# Unable to view eventgrid subscriptions in the azure portal. Unable to create new ones too

Tags: azure-eventgrid

I have around 12 eventgrid subscriptions already created for topic type 'Azure subscription'. Unable to see any of them in Azure portal since 30th May 2018.

I could see the list in azure cli (refer screenshot [list_shown_in_cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q8G2.png))
but could not see the same in GUI (refer screenshot [list_not_shown_in_gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FvQp.png)).

Moreover, I am unable to create new subscriptions too. I observed the javascript error in browser's developer console when attempted to create new eventgrid subscription (refer screenshot [error_creating_eventgrid_subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkROF.png)).

Comment: are all your event subscriptions for ContainerRegistry? Try to create another subscription, for instance for storage account. It looks like, starting from now, there is no topic type for container registry.

Comment: Nope, they are not for container registry. The topic type is 'Azure subscription'. Webhook url points to azure function app. I listen to vm deploy events, vm extension create/delete events. 
Issue I'm facing is, I could see the list of subscriptions in azure cli but not in the GUI of azure portal.

Comment: Issue resolved. I'm able to see the list in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

list of all supported topic types:

```
    {
      "value": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "provider": "Microsoft.Eventhub",
            "displayName": "Event Hubs Namespaces",
            "description": "Microsoft Event Hubs service events.",
            "resourceRegionType": "RegionalResource",
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "supportedLocations": [
              "West US 2",
              "West Central US",
              "East US 2 EUAP",
              "East US",
              "West US",
              "Central US",
              "East US 2",
              "West Europe",
              "North Europe",
              "Southeast Asia",
              "East Asia",
              "Japan East",
              "Japan West",
              "Australia East",
              "Australia Southeast"
            ]
          },
          "id": "providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes/Microsoft.Eventhub.Namespaces",
          "name": "Microsoft.Eventhub.Namespaces",
          "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes"
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "provider": "Microsoft.Storage",
            "displayName": "Storage Accounts",
            "description": "Microsoft Storage service events.",
            "resourceRegionType": "RegionalResource",
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "supportedLocations": [
              "West US 2",
              "West Central US",
              "East US 2 EUAP",
              "East US",
              "West US",
              "Central US",
              "East US 2",
              "West Europe",
              "North Europe",
              "Southeast Asia",
              "East Asia",
              "Japan East",
              "Japan West",
              "Australia East",
              "Australia Southeast"
            ]
          },
          "id": "providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes/Microsoft.Storage.StorageAccounts",
          "name": "Microsoft.Storage.StorageAccounts",
          "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes"
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "provider": "Microsoft.Resources",
            "displayName": "Azure Subscriptions",
            "description": "Resource management events under an Azure subscription",
            "resourceRegionType": "GlobalResource",
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "supportedLocations": []
          },
          "id": "providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes/Microsoft.Resources.Subscriptions",
          "name": "Microsoft.Resources.Subscriptions",
          "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes"
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "provider": "Microsoft.Resources",
            "displayName": "Resource Groups",
            "description": "Resource management events under a resource group.",
            "resourceRegionType": "GlobalResource",
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "supportedLocations": []
          },
          "id": "providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes/Microsoft.Resources.ResourceGroups",
          "name": "Microsoft.Resources.ResourceGroups",
          "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes"
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "provider": "Microsoft.Devices",
            "displayName": "Azure IoT Hub Accounts",
            "description": "Azure IoT Hub service events",
            "resourceRegionType": "RegionalResource",
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "supportedLocations": [
              "West US 2",
              "West Central US",
              "East US",
              "West US",
              "Central US",
              "East US 2",
              "West Europe",
              "North Europe",
              "Southeast Asia",
              "East Asia",
              "Japan East",
              "Japan West",
              "Australia East",
              "Australia Southeast"
            ]
          },
          "id": "providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes/Microsoft.Devices.IoTHubs",
          "name": "Microsoft.Devices.IoTHubs",
          "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes"
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "provider": "Microsoft.EventGrid",
            "displayName": "Event Grid Topics",
            "description": "Custom events via Event Grid Topics",
            "resourceRegionType": "RegionalResource",
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "supportedLocations": [
              "West US 2",
              "West Central US",
              "East US 2 EUAP",
              "East US",
              "West US",
              "Central US",
              "East US 2",
              "West Europe",
              "North Europe",
              "Southeast Asia",
              "East Asia",
              "Japan East",
              "Japan West",
              "Australia East",
              "Australia Southeast"
            ]
          },
          "id": "providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes/Microsoft.EventGrid.Topics",
          "name": "Microsoft.EventGrid.Topics",
          "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes"
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "provider": "Microsoft.ServiceBus",
            "displayName": "Service Bus Namespaces",
            "description": "Service Bus events",
            "resourceRegionType": "RegionalResource",
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "supportedLocations": [
              "West US 2",
              "West Central US",
              "East US 2 EUAP",
              "East US",
              "West US",
              "Central US",
              "East US 2",
              "West Europe",
              "North Europe",
              "Southeast Asia",
              "East Asia",
              "Japan East",
              "Japan West",
              "Australia East",
              "Australia Southeast"
            ]
          },
          "id": "providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes/Microsoft.ServiceBus.Namespaces",
          "name": "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Namespaces",
          "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes"
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "provider": "Microsoft.Media",
            "displayName": "Microsoft Azure Media Services",
            "description": "Microsoft Azure Media Services events",
            "resourceRegionType": "RegionalResource",
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "supportedLocations": [
              "West US 2",
              "West US",
              "West Europe",
              "West Central US",
              "Southeast Asia",
              "North Europe",
              "East US",
              "East US 2",
              "Central US",
              "East Asia"
            ]
          },
          "id": "providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes/Microsoft.Media.MediaServices",
          "name": "Microsoft.Media.MediaServices",
          "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topicTypes"
        }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error is invalidRG - are you sure the resource group and or resource your are trying to subscribe to are valid?

It may also be an invalid resource type that you are trying to listen to. Things like Container Registry are not yet supported. The full list of supported sources can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-sources

A good first test to ensure your subscriptions are still available and valid would be so search for them via [AZ CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)
. You can open it in the CloudShell or download to your local client and then run `az eventgrid event-subscription list`.

Comment: I could see the list of subscription in azure cli but not in GUI of azure portal